# VBA code returning copied values into a specific range based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out a macro to return a cell value in one worksheet based on cell value in another worksheet within the same workbook. The idea is to copy and paste the data into the date row while referencing a date cell on another worksheet. I am inexperienced in VBA and hope that this is something that can be accomplished just not familiar enough to write the code.

```
Sheets("Lookup Values").Select
Range("K4:N4").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("MFG Shop HC").Select
Range("AI31").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

The range AI31 is the data that needs to reference the tab ("Macro") Cell ('I13). something like: find date ("Macro").Select cell ("I13") then Lookup ("MFG Shop HC"). paste?

Comment: You can probably do this using formulas without VBA. Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I am using data that is generated daily from ADP (time keeping software). This data is replaced daily. I am charting in plant headcount (attendance) using this data. the workbook has 11 tabs to represent the different departments & the data that is pasted from ADP is counted and totaled by department and by classification of absence reason. The summary of this data needs to be placed into a chronological order based on the cell that is referenced in the Macro tab.